# Laravel Artisan make command issue

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-5.4, laravel-artisan, composer-php

I am trying to make a middleware using artisan `php artisan make:middleware AuthorizedUserOnly` but I get `ErrorException` like below.

> file_get_contents(/mysite.com/www/local/composer.json) Failed to open stream no such file or directory.

This is my document root.

```
-local
  -Laravel application folders
  -artisan
-index.php
-composer.json
.htaccess
```

I changed my directory structure to work with shared hosting. And It was working fine.

**KEY NOTES**

1. Other `artisan` commands work. Like I tried `php artisan route:list` & `php artisan config:cache` & `php artisan tinker`.
2. This directory structure works fine.But as the error says that it is trying to find `composer.json` in `local` directory while it is on `document root`.
3. `php artisan make:model` command spits the same `Exception`

What could be the possible issue and solution ?

Comment: Check the permission of composer.json file

Comment: @MeeraTank, 755 permissions. But even If it were permission issue. Other artisan commands would not work but they are working.

Comment: Also, why it is looking for `composer.json` under `local` directory as mentioned in the error ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution** : I moved my `composer.json` file to `local` directory and it worked fine. So new directory structure is

```
-local
  -Laravel Application Folders
  -composer.json
  -artisan
-index.php
.htaccess
```

**HOW** ?

I am not sure about this yet. But this is the possible reason. `php artisan make` command create some files. So to included these created files into system execute `composer dump-autoload`. So to run `composer` it looks for in the same directory where `artisan` lives which is `local` directory in my case.

**IMPORTANT**

I changed laravel default directory structure to successfully run my applicaiton on **SHARED HOSTING** which laravel **DOESNOT RECOMMEND**.

We should follow the recommendations made by laravel to avoid any similiar issue. Specially never to mess with default directory structure at least.